# How to create a new variable in R that returns 1 if a case has a missing value while another variable has an observed value?

Tags: r, na, imputation

I have two variables containing missing data `loon` and `profstat`. For a better overview of the data that are missing and are needed to impute, I wanted to create an additional variable `problem` in the data frame, that would return for each case `1` if `loon` is missing and `profstat` is observed, and `0` if otherwise. I have generated the following code, which only gives me as output `x[] = 1`. Any solution to this problem?

```
 {
  problem <- dim(length(t))
  for (i in 1:nrow(dflapopofficial))
  {
    if (is.na(dflapopofficial$loon[i])==TRUE & is.na(dflapopofficial$profstat[i])==FALSE) {  
      dflapopofficial$problem[i]=1
    } else {
      dflapopofficial$problem[i]=0
    }
    return(problem)
  }
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that could be improved here:

1. Remember, many operations in R are vectorized. You don't need to loop through each element in a vector when doing logical checks etc.
2. `is.na(some_condition) == TRUE` is just the same as `is.na(some_condition)` and `is.na(some_condition) == FALSE` is the same as `!is.na(some_condition)`
3. If you want to write a new column inside a dataframe, and you are referring to several variables in that dataframe, using `within` can save you a lot of typing - particularly if your dataframe has a long name
4. You are returning `problem`, yet in your loop, you are writing to `dflapipofficial$problem` which is a different variable.
5. If you want to write 1s and 0s, you can implicitly convert logical to numeric using `+(logical_vector)`

Putting all this together, you can replace your whole loop with a single line:

```r
within(dflapopofficial, problem <- +(is.na(loon) & !is.na(profstat)))
```

Remember to store the result, either back to the dataframe or to a copy of it, like

```
df <- within(dflapopofficial, problem <- +(is.na(loon) & !is.na(profstat)))
```

So that `df` is just a vopy of `dflapopofficial` with your extra column.

Comment: Worked. Many Thanks !

Comment: The new variable is not attached to the data set. When I try to find the frequencies for this variable it returns that problem is not found